# Rebasing on master without merging every conflict of each commit of feature branch

Tags: git, github, rebase, conflict

I want to rebase my branch onto main. My feature branch is 40 commits ahead of the master branch.

When I do a
`git rebase main`

I need to solve the merge conflict for the first commit, when that is done I :

```
git add MODIFIED_FILES
git rebase --continue
```

and I end up solving the conflicts of my 2nd commit. I simply cannot resolved 40 merge conflicts even that all of those first commits are rather obsolete compared to the latest development of my branch.

Is there a way to `git rebase` by doing solving the conflicts on only my latest branch's commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem :

1/ Squash my X number of commits (commit id <specific_commit>) in my feature branch first :

```
git rebase -i <specific_commit>
git push -f
```

By doing this your 40 commits become 1 in your feature branch history

2/ I rebase onto main by solving 1/2 conflicts only

```
# make sure that main is up to date
git rebase main
# solve conflicts
git rebase --continue
# might need to solve conflicts twice
git push -f
```

By doing this I get the linear history of the main branch into my feature branch which would make PR ready to be merged afterwards by the repo's maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the often overlooked [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) command ("reuse recorded resolution"). It applies a previous conflict resolution to an identical later conflict. This is what usually happens during rebasing.

Note that you can also automate running this command using a configuration variable:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, something that I might have omitted by the conflicts might be unique in most commits so im sure that `git rerere` will be of much help ?

Comment: Oh, I see. If every commit introduces unique conflicts then `git rerere` will not help you.

Comment: I think was I need is something of the sort no but im not sure ? 

I can squash my branch to prevent Successive conflict resolving. After, when I rebase I will only have to resolve only 1 conflict ?

Comment: Yes, if squashing is an option for you then you could do that an you would only have to resolve the conflicts of the one remaining commit.